# Pagination not working when adding pagin toolbar dynamically to grid Ext-JS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my app, everything should be dynamically. I'm creating a view like this:

```
this.store = Ext.create('Test.store.Users');
this.model = Ext.ModelManager.getModel(this.store.model);
this.view = Ext.create('Test.view.Users.Index');
this.view.init();
```

Ext.create view creates a grid and the init function creates a pagination toolbar:

```
init: function(){

var pToolbar =  new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        dock: 'bottom',
        store: this.store,
        displayInfo: true
});

this.addDocked([pToolbar]);

}
```

`this.store` has the right reference (checked it) and refreshing is working great but **pagination does not**! I'm always getting all results, not paginated. I've tried something like this inside init():

```
//bind a store to a toolbar
pToolbar.bindStore(this.store);
//reconfigure grid
this.reconfigure(this.store);
//load just the first page
this.store.loadPage(1);
```

Same thing. I'm getting all 240 records instead of 25. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `start` and `limit` parameters while loading the store. Also mention `pageSize` in store configuration or set is dynamically. You can load store like -

```
store.load({
    params:{
        start:0,
        limit: itemsPerPage
    }
});
```

If you are receiving data in response from server, then on server side you have to build `select` query according to `start` and `limit` parameters.

Comment: Thank you. Can I do this with local filtering, not remote?

Comment: Thank you. Can you then tell me, what I need to change to get this pagination locally. I'm accepting this answer as a correct answer. :)

In store, I put 'local' instead of 'remote'? What's with store.load()?